# How to send e-mails from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, server, email, execute-command

I have a Server where Calculations are being executed, they take sometimes days to finish. I would like to send an e-mail when the job is finished, maybe through a script or even with the `|`.

1. Before getting to the technical/command part I'd like to know what are the concepts managed to do this.

   - What do I need to achieve this? (Local MTA configurations for example? etc.)
2. I've read many blogs, even here in AskUbuntu, but they were from 2012, or 2014, suggesting `sendmail, mutt, postfix, at`... and many answers said "that's deprecated", "is no longer used", etc. or at least that's what I've understood.

   - So, what could you recommend to archive this with a 2017-2018 solution?

Thanks.

Comment: See the `mail` command, provided by the `mailutils` package for shell scripting. Alternately, python3 has a few good built-in modules for the purpose. So does perl, come to think of it.

Comment: We still use `mutt` for mails to local PCs but do not discard online mail: postmark for instance. Excellent API.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! A concept I would like to understand better is the "local e-mailing" I've always though that sending e-mails where entirely to e.g hotmail.com, gmail.com addresses. 

I would like to archieve that, postmark then is aimed to online then?

Comment: No you can also mail local users on a linux machine. That's how mail came to life: 1st we could send messages on 1 Unix machine to users. Then it went global :D "postmark" is fully online. Example: you can send a mailing from a cloud server using postmark api to users.

Answer (score 3):

Mailx still works.  Try this.

```
echo "This is a test" | mailx -s "Test01" mcjorch
```

This will send an email with the subject Test01 to the mcjorch account on the local machine.  The body will be whatever was read in from stdin.

You can do other things to get mail forwarded to some other email address (i.e. forwarding).  You need to know what your mail system is to know how to configure that stuff.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If whoever down voted it would explain why they down voted it, I would appreciate it.  What I gave is a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Because I found a previous configuration with it, I ended up using `ssmtp` to solve my problem.
But I would like to know, how does this work, what is needed, broadly speaking, to send an e-mail from one computer to another?

Comment: At a high level, you need a mail service running on a computer.  This is typically called a Mail Transport Agent (MTA) since it will listen for email on port 25 by default, and process any email coming in on that port.  If the email is for a local user, the MTA will place the email into the user's mailbox.  If not, the MTA will talk with other MTAs on other servers to get the email delivered.  The user reads and sends email using a Mail User Agent (MUA).  Nowadays, Outlook is the most well known MUA.